# Meaning of 苦労を掛けるね

Tags: grammar, meaning

I was watching the recently released episode of 無職転生 and one of the lines was translated in a way that was the opposite of what I thought it meant. 苦労を掛けるね (the protagonist's thoughts) was translated as "You don't make it easy", but I thought it meant that he was causing her trouble.

Here's a [link](https://ncode.syosetu.com/n9669bk/10/) to the chapter from the web novel that contains this scene. And part of the scene below:

> 「僕は知っています。父様はリーリャの弱みを握っています」
>
> 「え？　本当なの！？」
>
> 俺のでまかせを信じ、ゼニスは驚いてリーリャを見る。
>
> リーリャはいつも通り無表情だが、心当たりがあったらしく、眉をぴくりと動かした。
>
> ホントに弱みを握られているのだろうか。
>
> 普段の言動を見る限り、むしろリーリャがパウロの弱みを握っているように見えたが……。
>
> いいや。好都合だ。
>
> 「この間、夜中にトイレに行こうと思ってリーリャの部屋の部屋の前を通ったら、
>
> 父様が……なんとかを言いふらされたくなかったら大人しく股を開けって言っていました」
>
> 「なっ！　ルディ、なにをバカな……」
>
> 「あなたは黙っていなさい！！！」
>
> ゼニスが金切り声を上げて、パウロを制した。
>
> 「リーリャ、今の話は本当？」
>
> 「いえ、そんな事実は……」
>
> リーリャは視線を彷徨わせた。
>
> 本当に心当たりがあるのか。
>
> あるいはそういうプレイでもしたのかもしれない。
>
> 「そうね、あなたの口からはあったとは言えないわね……」
>
> ゼニスはその態度に勝手に納得した。
>
> パウロは目を白黒させて口を開き、しかし言葉は出せずにパクパクと金魚のようになっている。
>
> よし。畳み掛けよう。
>
> 「母様。リーリャは悪くないと思います」
>
> 「そうね」
>
> 「悪いのは父様です」
>
> 「…そうね」
>
> 「父様が悪いのにリーリャが大変な目にあうのは間違っています」
>
> 「……そうね」
>
> 手応えが薄いか……？
>
> いや、あと一息。
>
> 「僕はシルフィと一緒にいて毎日が楽しいのですが、生まれてくる僕の弟か妹にも、同じぐらいの年齢の友達がいたほうが良いのではないでしょうか」
>
> 「………そう、ね」
>
> 「それに母様。僕にとっては両方とも兄弟です」
>
> 「…………わかったわよ。もう、ルディには敵わないわね」
>
> ゼニスは大きくため息をついた。
>
> 苦労を掛けるね、ママン。

So which is the correct way to understand the final line in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation seems like the correct way to understand this. [Weblio dictionary's entry](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%8B%A6%E5%8A%B4%E3%82%92%E3%81%8B%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B) for 苦労を掛ける is:

> 相手に苦しい思いをさせる、迷惑を掛ける、といった意味で用いられる表現。苦労させる、などのようにも言う。 
> To make the other party feel strained, to cause trouble for someone. To give someone hardships, etc.

The mistranslation probably stems from differing interpretations from context. You could probably add in the implied parts of the sentence in two ways:

> （私は）苦労を掛けるね、ママン。

or

> 苦労を掛けるね、ママン（は）。

Since it seems like it's his mother that is being strained for words, the first interpretation  seems right to me.